# Excel - find and replace product description by product name

Tags: excel, formula, product

How can I in excel, use a formula to match a product name in column A from column B and copy or replace the product description from column C (being the description of products for column A) to column D (being the description of products for column B)? I have the product names in column A and wish to update the product description for the product names in column B etc. As the product descriptions in column B are old and need the new product descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

In D1, enter:

**=SUBSTITUTE(C1,B1,A1)**  and copy down

Comment: hey thanks for this format I will give it a try and see if that works.